# landing page for shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a splash or landing page in shinydashboard (or shiny if necessary). My main shiny app will have tab navigation etc. **but the landing page should not**. In fact, it should be completely different, maybe similar to this: http://www.dataseries.org

I know that I can add html pages into the same folder as the ui.r and server.r scripts but I have not found a way to reference that file when the app is starting up. An anchor tag could provide a link there but I want the landing page to automatically open when the page is called.

My reproducible code is pretty worthless because nothing has worked but I include it anyways, in case it make anything easier. This is boilerplate from the shinydashboard site.

**ui.r**

```
    library(shinydashboard)


    ui <- dashboardPage(

      dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
      ## ui.R ##

      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
          menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
        )
      ),

      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          # First tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                  fluidRow(
                    box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

                    box(
                      title = "Controls",
                      sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                    )
                  )
          ),

          # Second tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
                  h2("Widgets tab content")
          )
        )
      )
    )
```

**server.r**

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)

    server <- function(input, output) {
      set.seed(122)
      histdata <- rnorm(500)



      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
        hist(data)
      })
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at the [`shinyLP`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyLP/index.html) package?

Comment: I did and tried it but although some features are helpful I could not make them to work *outside* the navigation panels. Any thoughts how that would work?

Comment: Hi SprengMeister, did you find any working solutions for your problem? If so, could you post it in the answer section?

Comment: @Dendrobates I did not find anything workable. There are ways but I could not get anything useful to work. Sorry.

Comment: @SprengMeister there are some really cool examples online. Check this one out: https://github.com/nz-mbie/tourism-dashboard-public

Answer (score 11):

It's a bit hacked-together, but **you can use a modal dialog to replicate a landing page.**

Basically, use Shiny's native `showModal(modalDialog())` command to have a panel pop up over the app. The modal is created in an `observeEvent()` statement in `server.R` that runs exactly once when the app starts up. Custom CSS is included in the `ui.R` script that makes the modal take up the entire page. Here's the app:

**ui.R**

```
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  ## ui.R ##

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
      .modal.in .modal-dialog{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;
      }

      .modal-content{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
      }
    '))),

    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
        fluidRow(
          box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

          box(
            title = "Controls",
            sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
          )
        )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
        h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  observeEvent(once = TRUE,ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = FALSE, eventExpr = histdata, { 
    # event will be called when histdata changes, which only happens once, when it is initially calculated
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Landing Page", 
      h1('Landing Page'),
      p('Theoretically you can put whatever content you want in here')
    ))
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}
```

A few caveats:

- The CSS alters *every* modal dialog in the app, so you will need to add specific classes to this first modal to prevent all modals from being full-screen.

  - The modal technically loads after the UI loads, so there is a short second where the user can see the app in the background.

I believe you may be able to fix the latter by looking for an event that corresponds to the server loading the app, but unfortunately I am not familiar with any such event.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a hidden `tabsetPanel()` to create a landing page in this example. It contains 2 tabs

- Landing Page
- Content

It loads the landing page by default when the app loads. `updateTabsetPanel()` can then be used to switch from the landing page to the content.

**ui.R**

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "page",
      type = "hidden",

      #Your landing page
      tabPanelBody("landing-page",
        div(
          style = "position: absolute;
                   left: 0;
                   top: 0;
                   z-index: 10000;
                   width: 100%;
                   height: 100%;
                   background: lightblue;",
          div(
            style = "position: relative;
                     top: 30%;
                     left: 30%;",
            h1("Landing Page"),
            textInput("search", NULL),
            #Button to close landing page
            actionButton("close-landing-page", "Close") 
          )
        )
      ),

      #Your content
      tabPanelBody("content", 
        tabItems(
          # First tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            fluidRow(
              box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
              
              box(
                title = "Controls",
                sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
              )
            )
          ),

          # Second tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  #Observe event to close landing page and open content
  observeEvent(input$`close-landing-page`, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "page", "content")
  })
}
```